# ngb-progressbar does not appear

Tags: html, progress-bar, ng-bootstrap

I am implementing the ngb-progress bar into my html and when I add it to my code it appears in the console. I can change and edit the width and height and the div takes up space, however, the progressbar itself does not show. Just empty white space.

```
<div>
    <p>
        <ngb-progressbar [max]="100" [value]="25"></ngb-progressbar>
    </p>
</div>
```

this is the view in the console:

```
<div _ngcontent-c7="">
    <p _ngcontent-c7="">
        <ngb-progressbar _ngcontent-c7="" ng-reflect-max="100" ng-reflect-value="25">
            <div class="progress">
                <div aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;height: 5em;">
                    <!--bindings={
                        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                    }-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </ngb-progressbar>
     </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to include Bootstrap CSS. Please note that ng-bootstrap *requires* Bootstrap CSS 4.0.0 or later.

Comment: I ran npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 but still no difference. I don't believe it's a bootstrap issue otherwise it would have thrown an error on build

Comment: I'm pretty sure it _is_ bootstrap CSS issue. Lack of CSS is not throwing any errors (build or runtime). Just doing npm install on `bootstrap@4.0.0` is _not_ enough, you have to actually _include_ this CSS in your page...

Comment: it's part of my package.json file I don't need to include it in the page the modules take care of incorporating the ngb components but this one just doesn't show up

Comment: ngb components will _not_ incorporate CSS. You _must_ include it in your page (ng-bootstrap author here so fairly positive about it :-))

Comment: omg it worked!! I wasn't aware that they didn't incorporate CSS I am still pretty new to this. Thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: Also, how can I overwrite the bootstrap css styles for the progress bar? I've tried using .progress{} as well as adding a class to the ngb-progressbar tag but nothing seems to work.